# Javascript Express App with MongoDB and Authorization: My details and index view fails to load with the error that [value] is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { render } = require('ejs');
const courseRoutes = require('./routes/courseRoutes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { requireAuth, checkUser } = require('./middleware/authMiddleware');
const Course = require('./models/course');
const User = require('./models/User');

// express app
const app = express();

// connect to mongodb
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://sperry53:help@finalprojectgroup5.mieuiqn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=FinalProjectGroup5';
mongoose.connect(dbURI)
    .then((result) => app.listen(3000))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// register view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// middleware and static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.path = req.path;
    next();
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(checkUser);

// routes
app.get('*', checkUser);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home' });
    // res.redirect('/courses');
});
app.get('/courses', requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('courses', { title: 'All Courses' });
});

// course routes
app.use('/courses', requireAuth, courseRoutes);

// auth routes
app.use(authRoutes);


// 404 page
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404', { title: '404'});
})
```

courseController.js

```
const Course = require('../models/course');

const course_index = (req, res) => {
  Course.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .then(result => {
      console.log('Courses:', courses);
      res.render('courses', { courses: result, title: 'All courses' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const course_details = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Course.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.render('details', { course: result, title: 'Course Details' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(404).render('404', { title: 'Course not found' });
    });
}

const course_create_get = (req, res) => {
  res.render('create', { title: 'Create a new course' });
}

const course_create_post = (req, res) => {
  const course = new Course(req.body);
  course.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.redirect('/courses');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const course_delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Course.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.json({ redirect: '/courses' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = {
  course_index, 
  course_details, 
  course_create_get, 
  course_create_post, 
  course_delete
}
```

Things were working properly and then I added too much code without testing each addition because my other views were functioning properly.  This is the specific error:

ReferenceError: C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\views\courses.ejs:11
9|

### All Courses

```
10|
```

> > 11|         <% if (courses.length > 0) { %>

```
12|             <% courses.forEach(course => { %>

13| 

14|             <a class="single" href="/courses/<%= course._id %>">
```

courses is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12), :18:8)
at courses (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
at C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\app.js:43:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\snper\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 255\SDEV_255_Final_Project_Group5_TakeTwo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)